# Android blank bitmap

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, resolution, rescale

I'm creating bitmaps using inSampleSize.  I've come across an unusual problem.  On some images the rescaled image is blank.

Example 1:

Original: **4288x2848**
inSampleSize = **2**;
Rescale: **2144x1424**

*Result is a blank image*

Original: **4288x2848**
inSampleSize = **4**;
Rescale: **1072x712**

*Result is a proper image*

Example 2:

Original: **4752x3168**
inSampleSize = **4**;
Rescale: **1188x792**

*Result is a proper image*

This one fails at inSampleSize = 2 also.

Now none of the failures throw the obvious OOM error.  However, it certainly seems as I approach 3MB image sizes the BitmapFactory.decodeFile(..) is silently failing to create the image.

I can tighten the memory constraint, but I'd really like to know what is causing this artifact; appreciate any insight.  Thanks!

Comment: The issue is is that the Dalvik Memory Manager is denying your request for memory. If you look at your logs, you will see how much its requesting. Throw some logs into that using the System class and you'll find out how much is available.